# Prime_rehash_policy error while insert in unordered_maps using c++

Tags: c++11, unordered-map

We are using a custom library built buy another team and using it in our application built using c++11.
Since a recent upgrade in our library we are facing

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007efc338f2ce2 in std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy::_M_need_rehash(unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long) const ()
   from /path/share/custom_lib.so
```

During gdb I found the below error

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to Thread 0x7fc6b9ffb700 (LWP 196163)]
0x00007fc6d1364e82 in std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy::_M_need_rehash (this=0xb, __n_bkt=0, __n_elt=1, __n_ins=10903680147728276093)
    at /usr/include/c++/4.4.7/tr1_impl/hashtable_policy.h:492
492     /usr/include/c++/4.4.7/tr1_impl/hashtable_policy.h: No such file or directory.
```

When I checked our dev machine we have /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/
and the custom_lib.so dev system has /usr/include/c++/4.4.7/.

I understood that it was a compatibility issue with the compilers. But we cant go back to 4.4.7 because using Map instead of unordered_map will cause performace issues. The custom_lib team can't upgrade their compiler.

Thanks

Looking for a hack or work around to fix this issue.

Comment: The `this` pointer reported by gdb is `0xb`, which is probably due to a null pointer dereference. Can you post the smallest piece of code that causes the error? That might help localize why that’s happening. And have you tried running valgrind on the program?

Comment: mDSNLookUp.insert(std::pair<std::string,std::vector<std::string>> (pszDSN,vec));

Comment: Can you post a block of code in your question that we can run on our own and independently reproduce the error?

Answer (score 0):

I got the fix for this. It's basically because the dependent lib used a different compiler version. I used `std::tr1::unordered_map` and it solved the issue